# Not able to marge 2 pdf dynamically using PDFmarger in php

Tags: php, pdf, dynamicpdf

I am getting error "This webpage is not available" while merging  multiple PDF which generated dynamically using PDF marger.

Here is my code :

```
include_once(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php');

    $pdf = new PDFMerger;

    $pdf->addPDF('\PDFEBS.pdf', 'all');
    $pdf->addPDF('\PDFHI.pdf', 'all');

    //echo $basepath.$post['fileName'];
    $pdf->merge('file',realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'\SamplePDF.pdf');
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path before your PDF file includes like so:

```
$pdf->addPDF(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'\PDFEBS.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'\PDFHI.pdf', 'all');
```

Assuming your realpath returns the right path of course.

And try reversing your slashes. \ => /

Comment: still getting "webpage is not available"

Comment: Can you confirm on which line this error is thrown?